# Mounting weatherproof outlet box

Tags: electrical

I know this seems like a dumb question, but what is the right way to surface mount a weatherproof outlet box?  I wanted to screw it onto the wall but there are no holes for this.  It came with two little metal tabs which could be used like this, but it looks ugly with those sticking out.

[image]

I found an old box on my patio someone had mounted using 6 screws through the middle hole which is obviously not "correct", but it's lasted for years this way.
[image: box with ears]

These boxes have two dimples in the back which kind of look they could be punched out.  I tried hammering on it with a punch but they did not come out easily.  I think I will simply drill 2 holes in the back, but I'm trying to figure out what the designers intended.
[image: old improper installation]

Answer (score 5):

...the "intended" mounting method is the one you discard at the outset as "ugly."

As electrical equipment, when you discard the intended method (don't follow the instructions) you are violating code. A basic part of being code compliant is to follow manufacturer instructions, not come up with off-book untested kludges. That's also part of the UL listing.

Comment: Note that it is done this way so that you do not accidentally electrify something else, and also to contain a fire. These boxes serve to protect both the home and the people living in it. Screwing around with them can void insurance coverage and/or get people killed. Don't drill into the box to mount it.

Comment: Holes in the box can also defeat the weather proofing(keep out moisture) of the box.